# Why are the tags not visible as they are inputed?

Tags: support, tags, retagging

Just a couple of days ago I was editing a post which needed some formatting and re-tags. So I deleted the tag [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) and inserted [word-difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference) to be more clear and specific. Well, I *tried* to insert it! The tag [word-difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference) got shrunk into [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference). I repeated it again, thinking it might only be a glitch, but ended getting the same result. So I just submitted it with the formatting only.

Why does this happen? Are there any other tags too that get shrunk into more compact forms like this one or is it just a glitch?

Also if both are same in context meaning, why are two tags formed in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because [word-difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference) is a [synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/295232) of [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference). See the [tag synonym page for [difference]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/difference/synonyms):

[image]